# Sorting items by multiple characteristics

Tags: python

```
Given a conveyor belt (list) full of assorted Fruit instances (all Apple or Orange),
your job is to sort them into 3 bins (lists): apples, oranges, and rejected.
Test size ('S', 'M', 'L') and quality according to the given attributes;
Reject all fruit that is small (S), medium (M) if less than 90 percent quality
or large (L) if less than 75 percent quality
Return a tuple of lists in apples, oranges, rejected order
    :param assorted_fruits: list of fruits
    :return: tuple of three lists -- apples, oranges, rejected
```

I know how to sort them into lists based on a single characteristic like what kind of fruit as seen in my code, but I am unsure how to do it with multiple characteristics.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
apples = []
oranges = []
rejected = []

apples = [item for item in assorted_fruits if isinstance(item, Apple)]
oranges = [item for item in assorted_fruits if isinstance(item, Orange)]
rejected = [item for item in assorted_fruits if isinstance(item, Rejected)]
```

Comment: Can you show us an example input and corresponding output

Comment: So given [Apple('L', 60), Orange('M',91), Apple('S',92)] It would return in oranges([('M', 91]) and the rest would be in rejected.

Answer (score 1):

```
apples = []
oranges = []
rejected = []

for item in assorted_fruits:
    if  not (item.size == 'L' and item.quality >= 75) and not (item.size == 'M' and item.quality >= 90):
        rejected.append(item)
    elif isinstance(item,Apple):
        apple.append(item)
    elif isinstance(item,Orange):
        oranged.append(item)
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much.  You made it so much more simple than I did.

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. This would add to my reputation and let me help more people and also stop other people from attempting to help with a problem you no longer need help with.